# Product of uniquely ergodic continuous disjoint maps is uniquely ergodic

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $g: X \rightarrow X$ and $h: Y \rightarrow Y$ be continuous uniquely ergodic maps between compact metric spaces. Assume $g$ and $h$ are disjoint. Show that $g \times h$ is uniquely ergodic.

**Attempt** Let $\mu$ be the unique ergodic measure on $X$ and $\nu$ be the unique ergodic measure on $Y$. Then $g \times h$ is ergodic with respect to the product measure $\mu \times \nu$. I think the way to go is now to show that every other ergodic measure $m$ on $X \times Y$ yields a contradiction to the disjointness property of $g$ and $h$. Sadly I have no idea how to start this argument. Can somebody give a hint? Or am I on the totally wrong path?

**Definition** Two measure preserving maps $r: (A,\mu) \rightarrow (A,\mu)$ and $s: (B,\nu) \rightarrow (B,\nu)$ between probability spaces are disjoint if the product measure $\mu \times \nu$ is the only joining.

Comment: Can you include a definition of disjointness? I don't know how standard this term is.

Comment: Done. Should I also add the definition of a joining?

Comment: In your attempt, I think you cannot conclude $g \times h$ is ergodic with respect to $\mu \times \nu$. For example take the product of irrational rotation of $S^1$ with itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the irrational rotation case we need the additional assumption that for $x \mapsto x + \alpha$ and $x \mapsto x + \beta$ $\nexists n \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $(\alpha,\beta)\cdot n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So my basic idea is already wrong. Can you give me a hint how to start the exercise then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes like this:

Let $\mu$ be the unique ergodic measure on $X$ and $\nu$ be the unique ergodic measure on $Y$.

Now suppose $\eta$ is a finite $(g \times h)$-invariant Borel measure. The objective is to show there is only one such measure. Let $\pi_X: X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_X: X \times Y \to Y$ be the projection maps. Try showing the following:

1. Compute $(\pi_X)_*\eta$ and show it is equal to $\mu$ by unique ergodicity.
2. Do the same thing for $(\pi_Y)_*\eta$ and $\nu$.
3. Then $\eta$ is a joining by definition. Now by the disjointness hypothesis and your definition, $\eta$ must be $\mu \times \nu$.

(So you don't need to assume $\mu \times \nu$ is ergodic to start with.)

Comment: Your steps show uniquely ergodic, assuming we have an ergodic measure. But it is not clear to me, why there exists an ergodic measure for $g \times $h$ in the first place. Or am I missing something simple

Comment: @mathlettuce I didn't assume anywhere that there exists an ergodic measure for $g \times h$. The steps I outlined show that $\mu \times \nu$ is the only invariant Borel measure. From this we can conclude unique ergodicity.

Comment: Yes, I see you did not assume that there exists an ergodic measure for $g \times h$. Then my problem is, that I don‘t understand why you can conclude from unique invariant Borel measure that $g \times h$ is uniquely ergodic. For me seems, this just works if we already know that $g \times h$ is ergodic.

Comment: It is a fact that if there is only one invariant Borel probability measure, then it is ergodic. You should be able to find this in any book on ergodic theory. One quick way to see this is by using the theorem that the set of invariant Borel probability measures is the convex hull of the ergodic probability measures (derived from Krein-Milman theorem). So if there is only one invariant Borel probability measure, then it is automatically ergodic. See for example section 4.7 in *Introduction to dynamical systems* by Brin and Stuck.